# How to correctly merge one hash into another, replacing the first key. RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, merge, logic

Im currently trying to merge two hashes, I don't really have much else to go on but this is the result I need is showed in this example;

```
{key_1: 'i want to replace this', key_2: 'i want to keep this'}.merge({key_1: 'new text'})

=> {key_1: 'new text', key_2: 'i want to keep this'}
```

Currently what I've got looks like this;
 `@notification.attributes.merge({body: ()}).to_json` Im attempting to merge an replace the first key with the body element. What I'm really missing is the argument to perform the key replacement. If anyone has any direction, advice or even answers it would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails `#attributes` returns a hash with string keys:

```
irb(main):001:0> note = Notification.new(title: 'All your base are belong to us', body: 'Loren Ipsum...')
irb(main):002:0> note.attributes
=> {"id"=>nil, "title"=>"All your base are belong to us", "body"=>"Loren Ipsum...", "read_at"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil}
```

If you want to replace a key in the hash you either need to use a hash with string keys:

```
irb(main):003:0> note.attributes.merge("body" => "Moahahahahahaha")
=> {"id"=>nil, "title"=>"All your base are belong to us", "body"=>"Moahahahahahaha", "read_at"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "updated_at"=>nil}
```

Or you need to change the keys of the hash to symbols which can be done with [`Hash#symbolize_keys`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys):

```
irb(main):004:0> note.attributes.symbolize_keys.merge(body: "Moahahahahahaha")
=> {:id=>nil, :title=>"All your base are belong to us", :body=>"Moahahahahahaha", :read_at=>nil, :created_at=>nil, :updated_at=>nil}
```

This is a pretty common source of errors for new developers as Rails abstracts away the difference between symbol and string keys in many places through the use of [ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) or hash like objects like [ActionController::Parameters](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) that have indifferent access while Ruby itself is strict about the difference.

```
irb(main):008:0> { "foo" => "bar" }.merge(foo: 'baz')
=> {"foo"=>"bar", :foo=>"baz"}
irb(main):009:0> { "foo" => "bar" }.with_indifferent_access.merge(foo: 'baz')
=> {"foo"=>"baz"}
```

If you ever need to do this with a nested hash you can use the recursive versions [`deep_symbolize_keys`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_stringify_keys) and [`deep_merge`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_merge).

Comment: When you call `to_json` on a hash with duplicate keys you will get an invalid JSON object `{"foo"=>"bar", :foo=>"baz"}.to_json` -> `{"foo": "bar","foo":"baz"}`. Duplicate keys are not allowed in the specification and the behavior at this point is really up to the consumer. Usually browsers will just use the last key, but its also possible that a parser could raise an error.

Comment: This answer did help me with more understanding and provided useful links. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add ! in your merge operation, as when you are doing operation it is not effecting your actual object but will create new object. So your example as you said I did following to change values

```
{key_1: 'i want to replace this', key_2: 'i want to keep this'}.merge!({key_1: 'new text'})

# result
{:key_1=>"new text", :key_2=>"i want to keep this"}
```

please change following from

```
@notification.attributes.merge({body: ()}).to_json
```

to

```
@notification.attributes.merge!({body: ()}).to_json
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, whilst it may help. I'm looking for help with the condition for the merge, i.e. `({body: ()})` this section. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to change the order of master hash (the master is what you want to keep)

```
    [9] pry(main)> a = {:key_1=>"i want to replace this", :key_2=>"i want to keep this"}
    => {:key_1=>"i want to replace this", :key_2=>"i want to keep this"}
    
    [10] pry(main)> b = {:key_1=>"new text"}
    => {:key_1=>"new text"}
    
    [11] pry(main)> c = b.merge(a)
     => {:key_1=>"i want to replace this", :key_2=>"i want to keep this"}
    
    [12] pry(main)> d = a.merge(b); // <===== This is what you want.
    => {:key_1=>"new text", :key_2=>"i want to keep this"}
```

Hope it help. Thanks